# Windows Store Browse Button

Tags: xaml, winrt-xaml

I want to create a simple Browse button like that found on the Windows 8.1 Reader app:

[image]

However, after searching for an hour I'm still no wiser. There must be a standard Button style for circle buttons? And where would I find the browse icon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure this is the most elegant XAML in the world, but it gets the job done.

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource TextBlockButtonStyle}">
    <Button.RenderTransform>
        <ScaleTransform ScaleX="2" ScaleY="2" />
    </Button.RenderTransform>
    <Grid>
        <Rectangle Fill="DimGray" />
        <Grid Margin="7,5,5,5">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="22" />
                <ColumnDefinition />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="" FontFamily="Segoe UI Symbol" FontSize="18" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,-2,0,0" />
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="" FontFamily="Segoe UI Symbol" FontSize="12" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="Browse" FontWeight="Light" Margin="4,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  />
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Button>
```

Here's the result:

[image]

Best of luck!

Comment: Thanks Jerry. It seems crazy to me that this is the best way to do it though?!?

Comment: Yeah, I know. To answer your question though - there is no standard style for adding a circle around an icon in a button. Probably should have been, but there isn't.

Comment: Ok, well I'm sure it'll be there in Windows 10 ;)

Comment: Did I answer your question?

Comment: Yes, you did - sorry I forgot to mark it as answered. Done.

Answer (score 0):

you should see this

- [AppBar button style images](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj841127.aspx)
- [Symbol enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.symbol.aspx)
- [Modern UI
  Icons](http://modernuiicons.com/)

Comment: Thanks, but the AppBarButtons seemed to be styled to a fixed size, which is smaller than the button in Windows 8.1 Reader?

Comment: you can use a Button with the image want, and I think AppBarButton can be used anywhere, to use the Icon property with the images that resources provide...

Comment: Just to clarify having investigated further: I can't use AppBarButton because its template has a label TextBlock below which messes up alignment.

Comment: You do not define that label.... but you can use button with an image, see the WinRT Toolkit.